# How to recover if a disk with OS on dedicated server fails?

Tags: hard-drive, dedicated-server

Dedicated server on a private cloud that consists of four disks.

One of the disks contains the operating system (OS). If the disk fails, the server will not start, and we cannot extract data from the other disks in a simple way. Even if the disk is mounted as read-only, we still have to reinstall the OS, which requires the server to be shut down.

I would appreciate it if you could suggest some resources or books to mitigate these types of errors.

Additionally, I would like to know how to manage uptime with these "fragile" dedicated servers.

Comment: `What to do in this specific situation and how to manage uptime with these fragile (as opposed to vps) dedicated servers.` how would this be different from your data center? Does your hosting provider not have crash carts? Or out of band IPMI management? Those are a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague, predicated on a bad setup and appears to be hypothetical.

1. We pre-empt the issue by NOT using a single disk for the OS
2. If the issue did occur (or if the OS is on RAID and RAID device failed / disk controller failed) then the next step for most people would be to use the remote console facilities (IPMI, iDRAC, iLO) to map a virtual USB / reconfigure storage / restore or reinstall.

Comment: Should we install OSes to multiple disks? I plan not to use RAID for performance reasons (this is the storage server), and this implies I should install identical copies of OS and apps on at least 2 disks

Comment: Why not RAID1 for OS? Identical installations is impossible to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to not be in this situation in the first place: if service uptime is so important, it shouldn't be dependent on one machine staying up.

Failing that, you can either migrate off the machine to a spare then turn down the failed one, or if that's really not possible, then there's a few ways you could speed up the swap (eg, installing an os on the new drive before putting it in the server, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a "traditional" general purpose OS, use RAID. The "useful" storage performance does not depend on that: the crucial parts of OS are loaded into RAM and operate from these anyway, not accessing disk at all most of the time. So "no RAID for performance reasons" idea is totally baseless and your assumption is pointless.

There is a Linux-based dedicated storage OS, [ESOS](https://www.esos-project.com/). It is intended to be installed into USB flash drive and boots from it. It also relies on the fact the OS will simple operate from memory, you can even remove the flash stick after the boot. The configuration is managed in such a way so you can quickly prepare another USB stick and push a configuration and boot again into the "same" system.